# How to print python module hierarchy?

Tags: python

I have a file which is dynamically loaded. Because of the dynamic loading, I have no idea what its module path is, and all of my best guesses (per the filesystem structure) have failed so far.

1. How do I inspect the full module path from within the running file?
2. How do I walk the hierarchy programmatically?

(Python 2.6)

Comment: Have you tried the module's `__file__` attribute?

Comment: @Wooble The path in the filesystem is known to me. I am observing that the module path does not match it, I would assume due to the dynamic loading.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to import that module runtime anyways you have the access to `__file__` attribute of it, which will give you the exact location of your module.

for example:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: print os.path.dirname(os.__file__)
/usr/lib/python2.7
```

Comment: I have by trial and error determined that the module path somehow does not match the filesystem path. Is that possible?